# Mono.Zeroconf NuGet package will not install in Xamarin

Tags: android, macos, xamarin, nuget

I am using Xamarin 6.3 on a mac.  I am very new to Xamarin.

I have a project open.   I choose "Project" -> "Add NeGet Projects..."

I type "Mono" in the search box, and check the box next for Mono.Zeroconf, then choose "Add Package"

There are several lines of output, but the last line is:

```
Could not install package 'Mono.Zeroconf 0.9.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.4', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I have tried changing the version of my android package, but each one results in failure.

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 1):

This project doesn't support `Xamarin.Android` as it only contains libraries for desktop `.NET 2.0`. This library would need to support the `MonoAndroid` target or a PCL/dotnet standard target.

Sadly this library hasn't been updated since 2011 it looks like! Thus it is very unlikely it will support `Xamarin.Android` unless it's updated in the future.

Source:

https://github.com/mono/Mono.Zeroconf